# ios file encryption and encoding takes long time

Tags: ios, performance, file, encryption, aes

I am using Base64 encoding and AES encryption for files stored in memory. The problem is the encryption/decryption is very time consuming with high mb files say of some 20 mb. It is because a 20 high mb file on encryption will become some 50 mb. So the decryption of this high mb data will take time.  Is there any solution for reducing this encryption/decryption time. Or any other optimise method for file encryption.

Comment: are you using native Base64 provided by IOS 7?

Comment: no. this app need to support from ios 5

Comment: Are you using secKeyWrapper for your encryption/decryption? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html

Comment: no. can i use this for encrypting file. @jai

Comment: Yes you should pass nsdata for encryption. You can create nsdata from file.